# Авторизация open id pkce keycloak

Tags: keycloak

Я пытаюсь прикрутить авторизацию `keycloak openid pkce` на мое js приложение.
Кода дело доходит до обмена кода доступа возникает следующая проблема:
При попытке обменять ключ доступа на токен возникает ошибка браузера

> Отсутствует заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin

В панели разработчика я вижу что не было попытки отправить `options` запрос на сервер авторизации. Если сменить `'Content-Type'` на `'application/json'`, то предварительный запрос пройдет успешно, но тогда я получу `415` ошибку. Проверял в `postman`, сервер `keycloak` на `options` запросы отвечает правильно, заголовок `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` присутствует.
Вот пример функции:

```js
async function getAccessToken(code) {
  const tokenEndpoint = `${keycloakConfig.url}/realms/${keycloakConfig.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;

  const codeVerifier = sessionStorage.getItem('codeVerifier');
  const data = {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    client_id: keycloakConfig.clientId,
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: window.location.href,
    code_verifier: codeVerifier,
  };
  const response = await fetch(tokenEndpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: data,
  });
  const tokenData = await response.json();

  const accessToken = tokenData.access_token;
  return accessToken;
}
```